# When multiple push notification selecting one disappears others from the tray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification

I am having the case when i am getting multiple notifications and when i select any one of them it opens up my app and does according my code.Then when i check other notifications are disappeared from the tray. Is this the usual case with notifications that opening one will remove others too or I am missing something?

I also have the question about bedge icons for multiple notifications also it is always shows 1 on the app icon. on opening of any of notification i set it to 0(zero). Does this bedge manage by server? If so how server will identify that this device is sent this many number of notifications?

As bedge are always shows 1, if i set bedge count as

```
     int bedge = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
     bedge--;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:bedge];
```

It goes to negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

you're not missing anything its usual case just because by clicking on any noti your app is getting open so all were disappear because all are related to the same application that's why once you open your app from any noti other were disappears.

Comment: @eptdevloper, ok. Do you have idea about the bedge query?

Comment: @Roshni : in terms of what? i mean what is your question by bedge query? tell me your requirement or something logical that makes me understand to help you thanks

Comment: Like bedge count we have on our app icon when we get notification.In my case I get 1 everytime thugh i am getting 2 or more notifications. How do i increase that?

Comment: @Roshni you can mannage an array of badges and everytime you got responce then removeAllObjects from array and re-fill it

Comment: Still didnt get you.If multiple notification arrives and app is killed then how do we will be able to show bedge cound on app icon. Rather it is handle by our side or os or server?

Comment: it's a default property of iOS you need not to worry about i guess

Comment: In my case if i am getting 5 notifications, even though it shows only 1 bedge number at app icon

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36716/discussion-between-eptdeveloper-and-roshni)

Answer (score 0):

**About APNS:**
Once your app is registered to APNS you will receive the device token. That device icon your are passing to third party server and if third party want to send the notification to the device then it will contact to APNS and ask to push the notification.

**About Badges:**
The badges will handled by OS. That means whenever third party pushing the notifications to the device then OS is automatically increase the count.Once you open the any notification in device notification bar or lock screen it will directly navigate to the application. Because your app ID is registered to APNS and it automatically sets the count to 0.

Comment: In my case if i am getting 5 notifications, even though it shows only 1 bedge number at app icon

Comment: my question was not about APNS, I am asking if i select one notification from tray and open it up then others also removed from tray automatically.

Comment: Didn't get you.What is the solution and regarding which issue?

Comment: I Understand your problem now.I also faced same issue earlier.Solution is in your delegate method(didReceiveRemoteNotification) you will receive the server response including the text and badge count. First you need to check whether server is sending the badge count or not.  Server should mention the badge count and notify to device using APNS.

Comment: This is the answer for your previous question(Notifications in tray)
Now your application in background and assume you received 5 notifications from server. You opened one notification in the bar(tray) then it automatically moves to your application.Once it moved the remaining notifications also cleared because it is related to App ID and it is the basic behavior of the Apple. Take another example like you got 3 missed calls and once you opened the Phone app all the missed calls will shown.Once you exit from the Phone app all the missed call list is gone. Its a default behavior of Apple.